# Why can I not have the same Controller name in a different package with annotation-based configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
Jul 27, 2011 10:56:15 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet 
initServletBean

SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 

Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
[/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; 

nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

Annotation-specified bean name 'fooController' for 
bean class [com.fooapp.ctrl.FooController] 
conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name 
and class [com.fooapp.ctrl.admin.FooController]
```

In both packages I defined the Controller using the `@Controller` annotation:

```
@Controller
public class FooController {
...
```

Do I have to use a different name for the Controller in the `admin` package?

Answer (score 19):

The default bean-name for a `@Component` or derivative (`@Controller`, `@Service`, etc.) is the unqualified class name with a lower first character. In order to have those two controllers together, just set a different bean name (for at least one of them):

```
@Controller("secondFooController")
```

Check [this section](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-name-generator) of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

use spring.factories and add your controller classses in autoconfiguration.
Now you will have bean names with qualified names and that will not clash.