# how to work with multiple controllers in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

## Multiple controller class application

I am using multiple controllers in different packages but while starting my boot application,it is giving me start failure:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.xyz.UserIntegrationServiceApplication]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'userController' for bean class [com.xyz.a.UserController] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.xyz.b.UserController]
```

## Boot main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class UserIntegrationServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        SpringApplication.run(UserIntegrationServiceApplication.class, args); 
    }
}
```

## Controller code

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public class UserController {

    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/di/user", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@RequestBody(required = true) User user, @RequestHeader(required = true, value = HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String authorization) {

        return userService.createUser(user,authorization);

    }
}
```

}

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public class UserController {

public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/ds/user", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<?> loginUser(@RequestBody(required = true) LoginRequest login,
        @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {

    return userService.loginUser(login, headers);

}
```

}

###########

### I am trying to find out best possible way to make this main class access my controllers

Please help me on this

Comment: Could you provide your `Controller` codes?

Comment: updated the controller code..please check

Comment: Besides renaming one of the two controllers, is there a reason there needs to be two controllers? Based on code provided, looks like the createUser and loginUser methods could be in the same controller because they're mapping to different places after /api/ anyway.

Comment: I can put in same controller if I don't find any solution..but I want to have separate controllers because my API will hit entirely separate third party apps through controllers

Answer (score 0):

You need just to set different bean names for the two UserController.

Possible duplicate of: [Why can I not have the same Controller name in a different package with annotation-based configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842944/why-can-i-not-have-the-same-controller-name-in-a-different-package-with-annotati/6843360)